# Selenium reinicia configuración de motor de búsqueda

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Resulta que estoy haciendo un pequeño bot que va sacando información de una página web con la ayuda de Selenium y Python. Lo que sucede es que tengo que loggearme en la pagina cada vez que se lanza el bot desde selenium mientras que si lo hago yo desde mi navegador habitual ya me encuentro loggeado.

Me gustaría saber qué debería de hacer para poder mantener los datos de una sesión se Selenium para que puedan ser utilizados en otra. Se que se pueden configurar cookies pero quiero ir un poco más allá con historial, contraseñas, cuentas y demás.

Gracias de antemano. Un saludo.

Comment: Eso ya depende del navegador, no de WebDriver, lo que puedes hacer es crear perfiles y lanzar el navegador del driver apuntando a ese perfil, y eso se hace de maneras diferentes dependiendo el navegador.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo necesité algo parecido y lo resolví creando un nuevo perfil en firefox, almacenando en ESE perfil todo lo que yo quiero y luego lanzando ESE perfil con selenium:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('miPerfilFirefox')
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```